# Searching and printing a just certain words from a line of code in a text file

Tags: linux, search, printing, grep, command-line-interface

So on the command line in linux I am trying to search some HTML code and print just a dynamic part of the code. For example this code

```
<p><span class="RightSideLinks">Tel: 090 97543</span></p>
```

I would just want to print 97543 not the 090. The next time I search the file the code might have changed to

```
<p><span class="RightSideLinks">Tel: 081 82827</span></p>
```

And I just want the 82827. The rest of the code stays the same just the phone numbers change.

Can I use grep to do  this? 
Thanks

Edit:

Would it be possible to use it on this code too?

```
<tr class="patFuncEntry"><td align="left" class="patFuncMark"><input type="checkbox" name="renew0" id="renew0" value="i1061700" /></td><td align="left" class="patFuncTitle"><label for="renew0"><a href="/record=p1234567~S0"> I just want to print this part. </a></label>
```

What changes on that is the record number: `p1234567~S0"` and the text that I want to print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `GNU grep`:

```
grep -oP '(?<=Tel: .{3} )[^<]+' file.txt
```

Example contents of `file.txt`:

```
<p><span class="RightSideLinks">Tel: 090 97543</span></p>
<p><span class="RightSideLinks">Tel: 081 82827</span></p>
```

Results:

```
97543
82827
```

EDIT:

```
(?<=Tel: .{3} ) ## This is a positive lookbehind assertion, which to be
                ## interpreted must be used with grep's Perl regexp flag, '-P'.

Tel: .{3}       ## So this is what we're actually checking for; the phrase 'Tel: '
                ## followed by any character exactly three times followed by a 
                ## space. Since we're searching only for numbers you could write
                ## 'Tel: [0-9]{3} ' instead.

[^<]+           ## Grep's '-o' flag enables us to return exactly what we want, 
                ## rather than the whole line. Therefore this expression will
                ## return any character except '<' any number of times.

Putting it all together, we're asking grep to return any character except '<' 
any number of times if we can find 'Tel: .{3} ' immediately ahead of it. HTH.
```

Comment: @ManExa: Hopefully I've explained things well enough here, however if you'd like some more info on lookaround assertions see the page [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). See how you go anyway.  If have any problems just ask. Also, if you are happy with this answer, why not accept it? Cheers.